# Xamarin.Forms View-to-View binding without changing BindingContext

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, elementname

I have a `Button` defined in XAML that contains a `Command` including a `CommandParameter`. The `Command` binds to the current view's ViewModel, while the `CommandParameter` binds to another control within the current view. In WPF this would look like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
<Button Command="{Binding ViewmodelCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text}" />
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings), in Xamarin.Forms View-to-View binding is possible via changing a control's `BindingContext` using the `x:Reference` markup extension:

```
<Button BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MyTextBox}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text}" />
```

In this case, however, I'm not able to bind the `Command` to the global Viewmodel! Are there any solutions to this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you solve this?

what I did was to add a binding MyTextBox <-> viewModel like:

MyTextBox.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "PropName");

btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "CommandName");
 btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, "PropName");

Comment: You are right, this is how I solved it. Although I would have liked a shorter solution, it seems this is the only way to do it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ViewmodelCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyTextBox}, Path=Text}" />
```